# Validating object coming from the form params in the state machine before transition to certain state

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, state-machine

I'm using **pluginaweek / state_machine gem**
I need to validate object coming from form submitted by a user, but only before transition to a  certain state. Other states doesnt need validation.

I've got:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  state_machine :state, :initial => :draft do
    before_transition :draft => :emited, :do => :check_date

    state :emited
    state :draft
  end

  def check_date
   if params[:date] < Time.now
     false
   end
  end

end
```

But params hash isn't available in the model. Is there a way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :state, :initial => :draft do
    state :draft

    state :emited do
      validate :validate_date
    end
  end

  def validate_date
    errors.add(:date, "in invalid") if params[:date] < Time.now
  end
end
```

Hope this helps